# PG ETI SOVA plugin in Protege 4.3 doesn't seem to be working

Tags: ontology, graph-visualization, protege4

sova plugin downloaded from http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/SOVA for visualization

[image: sova plugin was placed in right place]

These steps suggested in above link, were followed.

choose Hierarchy Tree Vis in PG ETI SOVA tab;

choose HermiT in reasoner menu;

press Start reasoner in reasoner menu;

press restart in PG ETI SOVA tab.

[image: PG ETI SOVA]

I doubt if reasoner is working, the status window appears and disappears quickly, doesn't stay.

I have used SOVA a year ago, I can't figure out why it is not working now. I went back to protege 4.3 since even latest SOVA version wasn't compatible with protege 5. Please drop any hints. Thanks!

This is the partial error message
[image]

I am using SOVA 0.8.4   and Protege-OWL 4.3, which should be compatible as per http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/SOVA

---

Update 9/21/15: SOVA (8.4) tab does not load either.   This is also the case for Protege 4.2. Note that no earlier versions of SOVA are publicly available.

Error 4 Logged at Mon Sep 21 18:40:36 EDT 2015
UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/pg/eti/kask/ont/pluginSova/pluginSovaTab : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2128)
    org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1432)
    org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:72)
    org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1843)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:1723)
    org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:926)
    org.protege.editor.core.plugin.PluginUtilities.getExtensionObject(PluginUtilities.java:131)
    org.protege.editor.core.plugin.ExtensionInstantiator.instantiate(ExtensionInstantiator.java:74)
    org.protege.editor.core.ui.workspace.WorkspaceTabPluginJPFImpl.newInstance(WorkspaceTabPluginJPFImpl.java:99)
    org.protege.editor.core.ui.workspace.WorkspaceTabPluginJPFImpl.newInstance(WorkspaceTabPluginJPFImpl.java:30)
    org.protege.editor.core.ui.workspace.tabs.TabsMenuAction$1.actionPerformed(TabsMenuAction.java:50)
    javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
    javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
    javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)

### java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: If the reasoner hits a problem there should be logs visible in the command line and a red triangle in the right top corner of the screen. Clicking on it should bring up a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You have same problem with java version. Probably you have JRE 1.6.  to use JRE 1.7 or 1.8.

Comment: Try to use JRE 1.7 or 1.8.